# Python web-client to run javascript and get file download

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm trying to make a python script that downloads a file from a website,
but I wasn't able to find a solution for this:

```
<form name="dl" id="dl" action="/subtitle/download" method="post">
    <button class="Positive" id="downloadButton" onclick="DownloadSubtitle(this)" type="submit">
        Download English Subtitle
    </button>
    <input name="mac" id="mac" type="hidden" value="QvGN39b5EsEDobZfxpItT7XDYN2b4yBreI8TJIBfpdyi5SFknjIDx-DuLi9J51RZ0">
</form>
```

for reference: http://subscene.com/subtitles/the-big-bang-theory-sixth-season/english/649386

I want to be able to download the subtitle file.
I wasn't able to find how to get results from such javascript functions,
I think that if I get the data from that function a POST with it and the mac I would get the
file as a result.. Am I wrong?

*currently using urllib2 to open the page and HTMLParser to parse it and get the results.

Comment: "I think that if I get the data from that function a POST with it and the mac I would get the file as a result.. Am I wrong?" - What happened when you tried? Is `DownloadSubtitle(this)` critical to the process?

Comment: OK, so the problem was I did not POST to the /subtitle/download page, but to the same page.
I would still like to know if there is a way to run a javascript, for other porpuses....

Comment: Do you mean running select Javascript in a browser or outside of a browser?

Comment: I mean running the javascript just as a a regular brower (like firefox) would run it, but that python would.
I should be clear the end-goal here is getting data delivered by another request after the GET (like ajax does).
I Want this because when I GET, I do not see the full HTML of the site (as viewed when pressing F12 in a browser)

Comment: Please update your question with how you envisage this to work or the process you want to achieve and elaborate on "getting data delivered by another request after the GET"

Comment: BTW, you can run Javascript from the command line using something like Nodejs but you shouldn't have to as you can just re-implement the JS in Python. However, I think your issue is elsewhere